# SQL Server reproduce locks LCK_M_U LCK_M_X LCK_M_IX

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to reproduce some kinds of locks on SQL Server database. I can easily reproduce `LCK_M_U` when I create row and run in parallel many updates of this row.

Sometimes I could get `LCK_M_X` when I am doing constantly selects, inserts and many updates of inserted row.

But I need to reproduce `LCK_M_IX` so far no results. Any info how to reproduce it.

What is the reason and nature of generating `LCK_M_IX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LCK_M_IX` [occurs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) when a task is waiting to acquire an Exclusive lock. In order to reproduce it, you can simple create a table and add some records in it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Documents];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [DocumentID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[DocumentContent] NVARCHAR(MAX)
   ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY
   (
        [DocumentID]
   )
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Documents] ([DocumentContent])   
SELECT CONCAT('Some random text goes here - ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)))
FROM master..[spt_values];
```

Then in new query windows, let's perform modification on the schema:

```
-- query window 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Documents]
ADD [IsDeleted] BIT;
```

and here is our schema modification lock:

```
SELECT [resource_type]  
      ,[request_mode]
      ,[request_type]
      ,[request_status]
      ,[request_session_id]
FROM [sys].[dm_tran_locks]
WHERE [resource_database_id] = DB_ID()
ORDER BY [request_session_id]
        ,[resource_type];
```

[image]

Now, in separate query windows if we try to modify the data, we are going to be blocked as exclusive row cannot be set:

```
-- query window 2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE [dbo].[Documents]
SET [DocumentContent] = [DocumentContent] + ' incorrect text'
WHERE [DocumentID] = 1;

--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You can run [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive):

[image]

Also, you may want to read [Transaction locking and row versioning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017).